# Writing your own Makefile for OpenBSD ports

Tags: python, port, openbsd

I have an OpenBSD box running Python 2.6.  I want to install [py-setuptools](http://openports.se/devel/py-setuptools), but that package is built against 2.5.

I was curious as to what the Makefile for [py-setuptools](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/ports/devel/py-setuptools/Makefile?rev=1.13;content-type=text%2Fx-cvsweb-markup) looks like, to see if it mentioned anything about Python 2.5 as a dependency.  I did not find anything version-dependent.

I typed `make install` in `/usr/ports/devel/py-setuptools` on a whim, and it blew up because of failed missing Python 2.5 dependency.  That is expected.

My question is, **How do I modify the Makefile to build against Python 2.6** ?

I came across this in the [man pages](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=port-modules&sektion=5&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+4.6#CORE+MODULES), but I am still clueless how to specify what version to build against.  Also, I don't see anything that actually installs the egg.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `MODULES=      lang/python` line near the bottom of the Makefile.

Comment: Just curious, is it ok to modify a Makefile in the ports tree?  Is that behavior frowned upon?

Comment: You might want to make a quick backup copy, but yes. The worst it's going to do is not work, which is what the backup copy is for. Or you can always just DL a new copy from CVS.

Answer (score 1):

Ye almighty `MODPY_VERSION= 2.6`

Dont know how I missed that the first time...